# How to upload image in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to upload an image via `nativescript-background-http` plugin.

this my code:

```
var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
var request = {
  url: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "File-Name": imageFile.name
  },
  description: "{ 'uploading': " + imageFile.name + " }"
};

var task = this.session.uploadFile(path, request);
```

when I try to build my app, it will show the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'NAMESPACE' of undefined
```

The line of error is exactly this line:

```
var task = this.session.uploadFile(path, request);
```

any idea?

Comment: Check your versions and code with the demo in the plugin's repository. The demo is doing exactly the same (uploading a photo) https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http

Comment: Note that the above demo is using a dummy Node server that should be started from demo-server folder with `npm run start` (to be able to test the image upload)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution for you. To upload image using nativescript background http is now easy using a file stream method on your backend server.

https://www.ekpotoliberty.com/read/NativeScript-Image-Uploading-to-NodeJs-Api-+-Cloudinary-using-NativeScript-Background-HTTP/5dad52c76dc813685f8da26f

Follow the link above this will help you get through for nativescript core.